# Changing Linux hostname using PHP script

Tags: php, linux, sudo, hostname

I'm trying to change the Linux hostname with PHP script. I could do it directly on the Linux machine using the command **hostname**

But when I use the below PHP Statement .. it didn't work.

```
system('sudo hostname '.trim($Host));
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: I doubt very much that the web server user (apache/www) will have access to call this command, and rightly so. You don't want PHP or web servers to be able to make changes to the system...

Comment: Why would you want to change the hostname within PHP?

Comment: I'm developing an application which has cpanel features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your Apache user can run `sudo` commands without entering a password **(which, by the way, would be a huge security vulnerability, so please don't do it)** you could do this:

```
exec("sudo hostname " . $hostname);
```

In order to make sure your `www-user` can do this, edit `/etc/sudoers` with the following line:

```
www-user ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/hostname
```

Whatever you're trying to accomplish by changing the hostname, you'll probably find that you can do it another, safer, way. **To anyone reading this, I thoroughly do not recommend you follow these instructions, you are opening your server up to potential harm by escalating the priveleges of the `www-user` account.**

Comment: It's probably that your www-user isn't in `sudoers`. I really don't recommend doing this in a production environment.

Comment: I understand the security issue .. putting it aside.. www-data is added to visudo .. but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Try echoing the output to that command, should give an error if there is one. Does `www-data` have to input password in order to use `sudo` commands?

Comment: In `sudoers`, the user should be specified like: `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/hostname` (replace your `hostname` location) -- this way at least your PHP won't have *full* `root` access.

Comment: Excellent.. the issue is solved when I added /bin/hostname to sudoers. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this command with the function exec().
http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php